# Displaying larger articles of formatted text in Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, rtf

What is the best, or most used, practice for displaying larger bodies of text in an Android app. let's say I have some text that looks something like this:

[image: Text mockup]

So far I have only added smaller text elements in the form of TextViews and such. How would I display a text like this in, lets say a fragment in an activity?

Is there some way of displaying an rtf-dokument in a view? Do I need to convert it to html and use a WebView?

Is there a best practice for displaying larger formatted texts?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Web view for showing this kind of output

and make html String

```
String html = "<html><body>Hello, World!</body><table> </table></html>";
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";

WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Comment: It feels like a detour to me. But then again, so does a lot of other  things in Android. I look into it. Do you think it would be a good idea to have a separate html document and parse or show that instead of making strings?